# Python - Break numpy array into positive and negative components

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy arrays of shape (600,600,3), where the values are [-1.0, 1.0]. I would like to expand the array to (600,600,6), where the original values are split into the amounts above and below 0. Some examples (1,1,3) arrays, where th function `foo()` does the trick:

```
>>> a = [-0.5, 0.2, 0.9]
>>> foo(a)
[0.0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.0, 0.9, 0.0]  # [positive component, negative component, ...]
>>> b = [1.0, 0.0, -0.3]  # notice the behavior of 0.0
>>> foo(b)
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slicing to assign the min/max to different parts of the output array

```
In [33]: a = np.around(np.random.random((2,2,3))-0.5, 1)

In [34]: a
Out[34]: 
array([[[-0.1,  0.3,  0.3],
        [ 0.3, -0.2, -0.1]],

       [[-0. , -0.2,  0.3],
        [-0.1, -0. ,  0.1]]])

In [35]: out = np.zeros((2,2,6))

In [36]: out[:,:,::2] = np.maximum(a, 0)

In [37]: out[:,:,1::2] = np.maximum(-a, 0)

In [38]: out
Out[38]: 
array([[[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0. ,  0.3,  0. ],
        [ 0.3,  0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0. ,  0.1]],

       [[-0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0.3,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.1, -0. ,  0. ,  0.1,  0. ]]])
```